# How do I exclude null values when merging objects by key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, lodash, javascript-objects

Lets say I have an array of objects in Javascript:

```
  id: 1,
  name: 'Snowy',
  },
  {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Quacky',
  age: 13
  },
  {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Snowy',
  age: 1,
  },
  {
    name: null
  }
]
```

I have created a function to arrange them by a key:

```
const filter = 
        (pets, key) =>
                _(pets)
                .filter(pets => _.has(pets, key))
                .groupBy(key)
                .value()
```

Although, the output of this function when called persists the null entry:

```
{
  Snowy: [ { id: 1, name: 'Snowy' }, { id: 3, name: 'Snowy', age: 1 } ],
  Quacky: [ { id: 2, name: 'Quacky', age: 13 } ],
  null: [ { name: null } ]
}
```

Is there I way I can filter out any of the null values here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try by changing the method you use in in your predicate function from [`_.has`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#has) to [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get).

So, instead of checking if a *path/ key* exist in an *object*, you instead check the value of a *path/ key* within an *object* it its `null` or not.

> note: you might also want to check for falsy values here (such as `undefined`) instead of just `null`, since `_.get` returns `undefined` if the path/ key does not exist

```js
const pets = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Snowy',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Quacky',
    age: 13
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Snowy',
    age: 1,
  },
  {
    name: null
  }
];

const filter = 
        (pets, key) =>
                _(pets)
                .filter(pets => _.get(pets, key) !== null)
                .groupBy(key)
                .value();
                
console.log(filter(pets, 'name'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not first filter the array for objects that have a truthy name? For example someArray.filter(a => a.name)...group()...